# libcurl c/c++ Kerberos authentication

Tags: c, libcurl, kerberos

Does anybody have any experience with libcurl (C/C++) and Kerberos authentication?

I am able to set everything up and post data - however, now we have switched on SSO (via SPNEGO on a JBoss server) I am unable to authenticate properly, with authorization being downgraded to Basic.

At this stage I am using curl_easy_setopt(curl,CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_GSSNEGOTIATE) and have also set the CURLOPT_KRBLEVEL to "private".

Looking at the headers in wireshark, the response from curl doesn't provide any credentials - which is throwing an EncryptionKey exception on the JBoss server. I am able to authenticate on the server via .NET using cached credentials and a httprequest object. Only problem is we can't use .NET on this project.

Thanks in advance for any help.

- As an additional point. I have just seen that under libcurl Kerberos is only supported for ftp. I am trawling the source to try and confirm if this is the case. Anybody know of any other libraries that we might be able to use to perform our POST?

Comment: I have done it. Try to use the `curl` executable with `-v --negotiate` first and report back what it says. It does support Kerberos for HTTP fine, I am familiar with the source and can demo it if needed.

Comment: hi n.m - well, it appears the version of curl I am using doesn't support --negotiate.. which would explain a lot. I am going back onto the curl site now to try and source a copy and rebuild with what I need. (ironically this is the second time I have done exactly this..)

Comment: No.. not having any luck there. I can see in the build logs that it is including krb4.h etc etc. I set the path for my kerberos install. I've been building either using vs2010 or nmake - but no success. As far as I can tell I have modified the relevant config/make files, but clearly I'm missing something. As soon as i have a built version that works I'll let you know. G

Comment: ok - setup and ready to go. Just playing around with different options to see if I can get it going. I saw Daniel on haxx.se mention something about putting in an invalid user name to trigger negotiation. Anyway, any hints as to ordering and inclusion of options would be great. Thanks G

Comment: Daniel is right, it's a bug/deficiency of the curl executable. I forgot about it. `curl` must be supplied `-u someuser` for *any* kind of authentication to take place. With Kerberos `curl` takes the username from a different place, but it still demands the command-line option. You can put whatever username you want there. So say `curl -v -u x --negotiate yoursite` and see what happens. BTW I'm not very familiar with the Windows side of things. You may or may not have to do a `kinit` command there for `curl` to do the negotiation.

Comment: ok - from the command line i get the normal authentication and authorization headers and everything looks good. When I translate that into libcurl, the authorization header doesn't provide the full ticket string and authentication fails. From the command line I got the libcurl output and used it in my code. My only thoughts are that libcurl is being called from within a driver and there may be some issue with the credentials being accessed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok - for anybody that reaches this point...
I downloaded this version: http://curl.haxx.se/download.html win 32 generic.
It is compiled to run under ssh, ntlm and kerberos etc. The download includes the relevant DLL's you will need to create apps for any environment that requires cached credentials.
If you want specific code - pertaining to using callbacks, chunking etc, drop me a line and I can forward it to you. Given the flexibility of the curl library - it would be a bit much to just drop a ton of code here. Once you have the curl.exe up and running, there is a cmd line switch that can output the equivalent code to a text file (although it doesn't include information regarding any writecallback functions etc - just the easy setup options required). Thanks to n.m for your help - much appreciated. G

Comment: I think it will be useful if you could host your code online and link it here. I'm struggling with this same problem at the moment.

Comment: I would, but the code was done for a company several years ago and I no longer have access. The easiest way to get the general code is to use the cmd line, so - if you can get a compiled copy of curl to connect as you need, then you can output c++ based on that configuration. This will give you all of the setup options you need.